# Cached values from one select tag to another

Tags: jquery

I have a problem, I've created two select boxes.

After selecting value from first one it is passed and used in db select, second one is effect of db query, and after selecting value from second one input will show up that will show detail info.

Problem is after selecting value from first select tag and passing it to second, that value is being cached somehow so after selecting value from second select box I'm getting same amount requests that I changed value in first select box.

jQuery looks like:

First select box

```
function select_contract(folder_id, counter)
{
 var dataString = 'folder_id='+folder_id+'&counter='+counter;

 $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: $("#url_autosearch").attr('value'),
     data: dataString,
     datatype: "json",
     success: function(event){
         var option = $.parseJSON(event);
         $("#autocomplete-select-contract-"+counter).show();
         $("#autocomplete-select-contract-"+counter).html(option.contract_list);
         $("#autocomplete-select-contract-"+counter).change(function(){
             var contract_id = $("#invoice-contract-select-"+counter).val();
             select_service(contract_id, counter);
         });
     }
 });
 }
```

Second select box:

```
function select_service(contract_id, counter)
{
 var dataString = 'contract_id='+contract_id+'&counter='+counter;

 $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: $("#url_autosearch").attr('value'),
     data: dataString,
     datatype: "json",
     success: function(event){
        var option = $.parseJSON(event);

        $("#autocomplete-select-service-"+counter).show();
        $("#autocomplete-select-service-"+counter).html(option.service_list);  
        $("#autocomplete-select-service-"+counter).change(function(){
            var service_id = $("#invoice-service-select-"+counter).val();

            add_currency_value(contract_id, service_id, counter);
            return false;
        });
     }
 });
}
```

and detail info

```
 function add_currency_value(contract_id, service_id, counter)
 { 
 var selected = $("#invoice-service-select-"+counter).find('option:selected');
 var cost_id = selected.data('cost');
 var dataString = 'contract_id='+contract_id+'&service_id='+service_id+'&counter='+counter+'&cost='+cost_id;

 $("#cost-id-"+counter).val(cost_id);

 $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: $("#url_autosearch").attr('value'),
     data: dataString,
     datatype: "json",
     success: function(event){
        var option = $.parseJSON(event);

        $("#autocomplete-currency-value-"+counter).show();
        $("#autocomplete-currency-value-"+counter).html(option.currency_label);
     }
 });
 }
```

Comment: Why do you unbind `change` handler after first ajax call in `select_contract(folder_id, counter)`?

Comment: umm that shold not be there :P lemme fix it

Comment: So I was suspecting... Can you post your HTML, at least a part of?

Comment: This could be a bug in your service -- what is the code there?"

Answer (score 0):

If caching of AJAX requests is the issue as you suggested, you could try adding:

```
$.ajax({
     cache: false,
     ...
```

This will append on date stamp as a URL parameter to your URL assuring that the browser won't grab a cached copy.  I have ran into this issue many times especially when working with IE.

You can also do:

```
$.ajaxSetup({cache : false});
```

This will disable caching for all requests.